# How to calculate median survival in randomForestSRC

Tags: r, median, survival-analysis

I try to calculate median survival in randomForestSRC.

```
library(randomForestSRC)
data(veteran, package = "randomForestSRC")
train <- sample(1:nrow(veteran), round(nrow(veteran) * 0.80))
veteran.grow <- rfsrc(Surv(time, status) ~ ., veteran[train, ], ntree = 100)
veteran.pred <- predict(veteran.grow, veteran[-train , ])
print(veteran.grow)
print(veteran.pred)
```

I get survival function

```
veteran.pred$survival
```

and I want to get median of survival function (The value `veteran.pred$time.interest` for `veteran.pred$survival== 0.5`), for ample, for first row

```
a = as.data.frame(veteran.pred$time.interest)
b= as.data.frame(veteran.pred$survival[1,])
df =cbind(a, b)
df <-rename(df, `time` =`veteran.pred$time.interest`)
df$`veteran.pred$survival[1, ]` = round(df$`veteran.pred$survival[15, ]`, 2)
subset(df, df$`veteran.pred$survival[1, ]`== 0.5 )$time
```

The problem is survival function rarely matters exactly 0.5
In our case we get

```
[1] 1.00 1.00 1.00 0.95 0.95 0.95 0.95 0.93 0.93 0.93 0.93 0.93 0.93 0.93 0.90 0.90 0.90 0.87 0.87 0.87
[21] 0.87 0.87 0.86 0.76 0.76 0.67 0.67 0.67 0.67 0.67 0.67 0.66 0.66 0.66 0.66 0.66 0.65 0.64 0.57 0.57
[41] 0.57 0.57 0.57 0.57 0.57 0.48 0.45 0.39 0.39 0.32 0.32 0.29 0.29 0.29 0.29 0.26 0.26 0.25 0.25 0.25
[61] 0.25 0.25 0.25 0.25 0.20 0.20 0.20 0.20 0.20 0.20 0.18 0.18 0.18 0.16 0.16 0.16 0.14 0.14 0.14 0.11
[81] 0.07 0.07
```

So we have nearest values `0.57` & `0.48`
How to calculate median survival?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that `time.interest` is the correct item to use for that purpose, because it's length is much longer than the number of cases in the validation set. (That said, I'm not sure exactly what it really is supposed to tell you.) If you look at the output of `str(veteran.pred)` you see at the top:

```
str(veteran.pred)
List of 32
 $ call          : language generic.predict.rfsrc(object = object, newdata = newdata, outcome.target = outcome.target,      importance = impo| __truncated__ ...
 $ family        : chr "surv"
 $ n             : int 27
 $ ntree         : num 100
 $ yvar          :'data.frame': 27 obs. of  2 variables:
  ..$ time  : int [1:27] 100 384 123 22 21 139 31 51 54 132 ...
  ..$ status: int [1:27] 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ yvar.names    : chr [1:2] "time" "status"
 $ xvar          :'data.frame': 27 obs. of  6 variables:
  ..$ trt     : int [1:27] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
  ..$ celltype: int [1:27] 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 3 ...
  ..$ karno   : int [1:27] 70 60 40 60 40 80 75 60 70 80 ...
  ..$ diagtime: int [1:27] 6 9 3 4 2 2 3 1 1 5 ...
  ..$ age     : int [1:27] 70 42 55 68 55 64 65 67 67 50 ...
  ..$ prior   : int [1:27] 0 0 0 0 10 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ xvar.names    : chr [1:6] "trt" "celltype" "karno" "diagtime" ...
 # --- snipped
```

I think that since 27 is the number of rows of `veteran[-train , ]`, that you need to use the `yvar` item in the prediction list:

```
 str(veteran.pred$yvar)
#'data.frame':  27 obs. of  2 variables:
# $ time  : int  100 384 123 22 21 139 31 51 54 132 ...
# $ status: int  0 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
?survfit
 survfit(Surv(time,status)~1  , data=veteran.pred$yvar)
#Call: survfit(formula = Surv(time, status) ~ 1, data = veteran.pred$yvar)
#
      n  events  median 0.95LCL 0.95UCL 
     27      24      54      49     139 
plot( survfit(Surv(time,status)~1  , data=veteran.pred$yvar) )
```

[image]

I have serious reservations about recommending this procedure. Notice that there is als another item named yvar inside the forest node of that list and it has 110 rows (so it's the original data). IOf you look at the results of a traditional KM curve on an unadjusted analsysis you get:

```
survfit(Surv(time,status)~1  , data=veteran.pred$forest$yvar) 
Call: survfit(formula = Surv(time, status) ~ 1, data = veteran.pred$forest$yvar)

      n  events  median 0.95LCL 0.95UCL 
    110     104      87      53     111
```

I think 27 cases from an 80:20 CV strategy is going to give a very unstable estimating method for the median, especially when there are categorical predictors. I also think that the random forrest paradigm should be able to derive useful predictions from the entire dataset without using a cross-validation type splitting of data.

Comment: I agree with you but I think that `rfsrc` give us more exact value and `veteran` is just a toy example

Comment: So the reason there's,  no check is that I expressed reservations?